# TCP/IP not working between two computers

Tags: tcp, server, ip, client, protocols

I am making a TCP/IP connection. I have these codes:

server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(){
  int serverid, clientid, n = 0, len;
  char msgsend[512], msgrecv[512];
  struct sockaddr_in server,client;

  serverid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (serverid < 0) {
    puts("Error creating socket\n");
    return -1;
  }

  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  memset(msgrecv, 0, sizeof(msgrecv));

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  server.sin_port = htons(5000);

  if(bind(serverid, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
    printf("Error binding\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if( listen(serverid, 10) < 0){
    printf("ERROR");
    return -1;
  }
  len = sizeof(client);
  clientid = accept(serverid, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
  if (clientid < 0) {
    printf("Connection error\n");
    return -1;
  }
  puts("Connected to client");

  while(1){
    n =  recv(clientid, msgrecv, sizeof(msgrecv) - 1, 0);
    if(n < 0){
      printf("Error while reading...\n");
      return -1;
    }

    printf("client says:\n");
    msgrecv[n] = 0;
    fputs(msgrecv, stdout);
    printf("\n");
    printf("enter your reply\n");
    gets(msgsend);
    send(clientid, msgsend, sizeof(msgsend) - 1, 0);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
  int sock, n = 0;
  char msgsend[512], msgrecv[512];
  struct sockaddr_in server; 


  memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
  memset(msgrecv, 0, sizeof(msgrecv));

  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sock == -1){
    printf("Could not create a socket!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.112.130");
  server.sin_port = htons(5000);


  printf(" Trying to connect...\n");

  if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
    printf("Error:Connection failed\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Connected\n");
  while(1){
    printf("please enter your reply\n");
    gets(msgsend);

    send(sock, msgsend, sizeof(msgsend) - 1, 0);
    n = recv(sock, msgrecv, sizeof(msgrecv) - 1, 0);

    if(n < 0){
      printf("Read error\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("server says:");
    msgrecv[n] = 0;
    fputs(msgrecv, stdout);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I run first ./server and then ./client in another terminal. If I use the same computer it works fine, but if I want to use server on a computer and client on another one it never connects.
I don´t know what I am doing wrong. Maybe I have to use another IP? Some part of the code must be different for foreign computers?

Note: one computer is a desktop with ethernet and the other one is a laptop connected to te same router by WiFi.

Comment: What is the OS on the computers?   If it's windows, try to disable the firewall, if linux, enable that port on iptables or whatever firewall it is. Since the server and client work properly on the same machine, probably the issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to debug this kind of stuff is to try to ping in both directions, and see whether it works. If it doesn't you have to check the configuration of the routing-tables as well as your interfaces on the devices and the forwarding/firewall/nat setup on the router. Ensure that pinging in both directions works afterwards.

If that does work, test whether you can use TCP with some simple program like `nc` or even your own server. If pinging works, but the TCP connection does not, then it is likely to be a firewall-setting on one of the involved hosts, most often the server. Adjust the settings then test again. If you are not sure whether your own application works, you probably used `nc` at this point to test the connection, and you can now continue testing your application.